# PowerShell Compare AD Groups but show only these what I need

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that is generating from a file.txt a list of users and groups where they belong to.

The next step that I need to achieve is to confirm if the group from file Groups.txt is assigned to users. 
To do this I used logical operator -contains so the code is looking like that:

```
$UserList = Get-Content ("C:\users.txt")
$GroupList = Get-Content ("C:\Groups.txt")
$result = @()

foreach ($UserList in $UserList){
    $data = New-Object PSObject
    $Group = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $UserList | foreach {$_.SamAccountName}) -contains $GroupList
    $data = get-aduser $Userlist -properties samaccountname,givenname,surname | select samaccountname,givenname,surname, @{name="Groups";expression={$Group}}
    $result += $data 
} 
$result
```

The code is working when I have only one group in file Groups.txt. If I have two or more it is applying only the last one with value True

The resolution what I expecting is

When the user has one or multiple groups from the file Group.txt script should mention that group name and nothing else.

To be more precise I need something like that as results:

```
samaccountname givenname surname       Groups
-------------- --------- -------       ------
User           FirstName Surname        False (or anything)
User1          Firstname Surname        Group1, Group2, Group3
```

Many thanks for any help in this matter.

Comment: `-contains` is used when the left-hand side (LHS) of the comparison is a collection and the RHS is a single item. Use `-in` when the LHS is the single item and the RHS is the collection. Your foreach loop has issues. `foreach ($users in $users)` just does nothing since `$users` is empty.

Comment: Your for each loop is broken, you are using `$Users in $Users` which doesn't make sense and when using `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` you shouldn't be using `$UserList`, you should be using the `foreach` variable :)

Comment: Thank you @I.TDelinquent I corrected it, it was my mistake during copying the script.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I tried to replace -in instead -contains and it gave me nothing than False response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$UserList = Get-Content "C:\users.txt"
$GroupList = Get-Content "C:\Groups.txt"

$result = foreach ($User in $UserList) {
    $Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User |
        Where SamAccountName -in $GroupList
    Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties GivenName,Surname |
        Select-Object SamAccountName,GivenName,Surname,@{name="Groups";expression={$Groups.SamAccountName}}
}
$result
```

When using a `foreach` loop, the proper syntax is `foreach ($<item> in $<collection>) { statements }`. `$<item>` is just a variable that you can reference within the statements, and it should be a variable that has ***not*** been assigned up until that point. See [About_Foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7).

If your `foreach` statements produce output as in this case, they can simply be collected by assigning a variable to the `foreach` loop. This will result in a more efficient array assignment. Using `+=` to effectively expand an array, just results in creating a new array on each loop iteration that is bigger than the previous. It is not efficient and is unnecessary in cases like these.

Regarding collection comparison, `-contains` is used when comparing a left-hand side (LHS) single item with a right-hand side (RHS) collection. A sample syntax would be `$<collection> -contains $<single_item>`. `-in` is used when comparing a LHS single item with a RHS collection. A sample syntax would be `$<single_item> -in $<collection>`. See [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7).

Since you ultimately wanted to gather groups from a command output based on a certain condition, that is a prime candidate for `Where` or `Where-Object`. It's pseudo code usage is `out of these 20 items, show me the ones that meet a certain condition`. See [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Where-Object?view=powershell-7).